# How come this select statement returns 01/01/0001 and null, but only for a few columns?

Tags: c#, sql-server, string, datetime, idbconnection

I would like to read data from an SQL database, export it to XML and upload it to sharepoint.
However, when using a SELECT statement via an IDbConnection to first read from the SQL database, I get unexpected returns. Can anyone explain why it returns 01/01/0001 00:00:00 and null for some columns?

## Desired Result (as readable on the SQL server)

[image]

## Undesired Result (as queried via IDbConnection)

[![date     name    check-in        time of latest event    latest event    current status
[image: 2022-09-12 A 01/01/0001 00:00:00 01/01/0001 00:00:00 null null 2022-09-12 B 01/01/0001 00:00:00 01/01/0001 00:00:00 null null 2022-09-12 C 01/01/0001 00:00:00 01/01/0001 00:00:00 null null][2]][2]]

```
    public void SQL2SP()
    {
        using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(Helper.CnnVal("")))
        {
            var presence = connection.Query<Presence>("SELECT * FROM ..."); # this is the statement that returns unexpected results
            Events events = new Events();                
            var newData =
                from element in presence
                group element.Name by new { element.Date, element.Name, element.CheckIn, element.TimeOfLatestEvent, element.LatestEvent, element.Status }
                into g
                select new XElement("DATA",
                    new XAttribute("date", XmlConvert.ToString(g.Key.Date, "yyyy-MM-dd")),
                    new XAttribute("name", g.Key.Name),
                    new XAttribute("checkIn", XmlConvert.ToString(g.Key.CheckIn, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")),
                    new XAttribute("timeOfLatestEvent", XmlConvert.ToString(g.Key.TimeOfLatestEvent, "yyyy-MM-dd  HH:mm:ss")),
                    new XAttribute("latestEvent", g.Key.LatestEvent),
                    new XAttribute("currentStatus", g.Key.Status));

    

    public class Presence
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime CheckIn { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimeOfLatestEvent { get; set; }
        public string LatestEvent { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }       
    }
```

Comment: Your images have different names to that defined in the code; I *assume* that isn't the problem

Comment: because it found the name and date, I thought it assigned it in the same order as listed in the class, but after rearranging, it still found the name. I think you are right. I'll try some more. edit: oké that was it, thank you very much!

Comment: If you are using Dapper (which I think you are) then it does match on the returned column name matching a property name, and not just on ordinal position. So for the unmatched properties you are just getting the default value back. Give your columns a different alias and your query should work.

Comment: On an unrelated note, the group by in your linq seems redundant as you are grouping by all the columns and not aggregating. It is perhaps removing duplicates, but you'd likely be better doing this in the database via SQL, or more simply `presence.Distinct().Select (g => new XElement("DATA", ....)`